# How to set junit 4 as default runner in Eclipse, in android test project

Tags: android, junit

I am using eclipse helioes 3.6.2 and i want to create a android test project.
At the time of running the test suite, eclipse is taking junit 3 runner as default.
But, I want to make the runnner as junit 4 and in eclipse plugin there are also all the jars are available e.g.junit 3.8 as well as junit 4.
Please provide me some guidelines so that I can execute this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports **JUnit 3**, so if your intention is to run android tests you should stick with it.

Remember that the tests will be run on a device or emulator featuring that version so it doesn't matter the version your host computer could have.

Comment: i m trying to set default runner as junit 4. I dont want junit 3 as default runner.how it can be done???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android test framework (extending from TestCase, AndroidTestCase, etc., as recommend [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)), then you won't be able to use JUnit4. JUnit3 is built-into the Android test framework (JUnit3 source actually bundled into android.jar). To see what i mean, you can run the following command to check out the contents of android.jar.

```
$ jar tf android.jar | grep junit
junit/
junit/framework/ 
junit/framework/Assert.class
...
```

You can, however, run Android unit tests without the Android test framework. I use [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/index.html) to do this. Using Robolectric instead of the Android test framework, you can leverage JUnit4 instead of JUnit3.

Here's the **gotcha** for using JUnit4 with Robolectric: Once you have Robolectric set up to run your tests, **make sure your JUnit4 jar is added to your classpath before the Android SDK. Otherwise, the built-in JUnit4 classes will be used instead of the JUnit4 classes**.